# Can tikzcd nodes be placed automatically in displaystyle?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-cd, displaystyle

I've been converting from `xy-pic` over to `tikz-cd`. One thing I liked about `xy-pic` is that if I include in my file

```
\let\objectstyle=\displaystyle
```

then all of the nodes in my `xymatrix` diagrams are automatically in display style.  That's the style I want and I don't want to have to put a `\displaystyle` tag in every entry.

Is there a way to do this in `tikzcd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly not the easiest interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  cells={font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
\bigoplus_{i=1}^n X_i \arrow[r,"\sigma"] & \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in simple words the request of the OP, please? I have not understood it. Thanks. And what is the meaning of the use of displaystyle?

Comment: @Sebastiano By default, cells are typeset in `\textstyle`.

Comment: @Jim I wouldn't use it, however.

Comment: Why not?  You would manually put a `\displaystyle` tag in every cell?

Comment: @Jim In the ones where it is *really* necessary.

Comment: That would be almost all of them in the diagrams I'm creating.